How to Get Worldwide Sales Reports from App Store Connect API?
I'm currently using the App Store Connect API to download both sales and finance reports.
Endpoints I'm using:

Finance Reports: GET https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/financeReports
Sales Reports: GET https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/salesReports

Each endpoint requires different filters. For the finance reports, I can specify the regionCode and get finance data for specific regions. However, for the sales report endpoint, I noticed that there is no such option to specify the regionCode.
Whenever I download the sales report, it defaults to the European region.
Issue: I need to retrieve worldwide sales reports, but it seems like there is no way to control the region in the sales report endpoint. How can I get sales data for other regions or worldwide data?
Example request (sales report):
GET https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/salesReports?filter[reportDate]=2024-09&filter[reportType]=SALES&filter[vendorNumber]=xxxxx&filter[frequency]=MONTHLY&filter[reportSubType]=SUMMARY


Is there any way to get sales reports for all regions, or am I missing something in the API documentation? Any help or workaround would be appreciated!
